# Adding All Array Elements Together

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to know how I could add all of the elements of a float array together and make the sum float average;. Would I have to use a for loop or is there another way to add element 0 with 1 with 2 with 3, etc.?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Adding a bunch of floats is tricky, does the result have to be "as precise as possible", just "a bit precise" or can it be "naively sum them" (the difference with the actual sum can be quite big in that case)

Comment: @harold: from another question of Chris, it seems that those are grades, so the magnitude of the elements should be about the same. In this case, I think precision is not too much of an issue.

Answer (score 7):

You may use a for loop, or you can use [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  float arr[17] = { 1, 2, 3, };

  //Sum the array
  const float sum = std::accumulate(arr, arr+17, 0.0 ); 

  std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";
  std::cout << "Average: " << sum/17 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: while a good answer, that comment in the middle is a bit misleading :D

Comment: Thanks, @MooingDuck. As you might imagine, I didn't write my answer from scratch. I cribbed it from a "how to sum `std::vector`" example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::accumulate`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html).